# PHP function return does not stay within HTML Document

Tags: php, html, function, multidimensional-array

I'm pushing myself to make use of functions more often and have hit a wall with what is going on with my function return.

This code used here is pulled out of a much larger area of code to make it easier to work with here, so treat it more like test code then something that is going to do anything that makes sense.  All this test code performs the same as my full code and replicates my problem.

At the end of the code I have sample information being used for this illustration.  The code is building a dynamic form.

function formInputTypeSelector uses the variable built with (${'doorFinish' . $finish}[$series]) to identify the array to pass as part of the variables when the function is called.  So in this case, that is $doorFinishTrack[140].

That function then calls the appropriate input type function identified (function radioInputs in this test code) and returns the form for that input type.

The functions are all working fine.  The problem I am having is that if I echo my function return (echo $inputForm), my form ends up out of the document flow and not inside the div's I want it in.  I know that I should use **return** (return $inputForm) to fix this, but when I do my form no longer contains the function output.

I've tried everything I can think of and searched online for several hours now. I understand I probably have an issue here with server-side scripting versus the local HTML and the timing of this and what is called first.

My question is, how can I properly return the output from function radioInputs into the dynamically built form and keep it in the document flow?

```
<?php 
    $category = '';

    // 4.0  Track
    $doorFinishTrack = array(
        '140' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 0, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '220' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '240' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '440' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '540' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '640' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 0, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '740' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 0, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '2100' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 0
        ),
        '3300' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 0, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 0, 'Heavy Duty Aluminum Ceiling Guard with Seperate Track' => 1
        )
    );

    //parse the call and pas on the specific input type function
    function formInputTypeSelector ($inputArray, $series, $finish, $inputType, $arg1, $arg2) {
            // Call input type function
            foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
                $inputName = $finish . $key;
                $inputLabel = $key;
                $inputFunction = $inputType . 'Inputs';
                $inputFunction($inputName, $inputLabel, $arg1, $arg2);
            }
    } //end formInputTypeSelector

    // Specific input types called by formInputTypeSelector
    function radioInputs ($inputName, $inputLabel) {
        $inputForm = '';
        $inputForm .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $inputName . '" id="' . $inputName . '">' . $inputLabel . '</br>';
        echo $inputForm;
    } //end radioInputs

    // other types of input functions
        // ... code here

    //dynamically build the form based on the array called and the input form type desired.

        $finish = 'Track';
        $series = 140;
        $category .= 'Where the form starts</div> <!-- End tracksGroup -->';
        $category .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        $category .= '<div><!-- inputs -->';
        $category .= formInputTypeSelector((${'doorFinish' . $finish}[$series]), $series, $finish, 'radio', '', '');
        $category .= '</div><!-- end inputs -->';
        $category .= 'Where the form ends<div class="clearfix"></div>';

        echo $category;
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this.  Its amazing what a night of sleep and fresh eyes looking at a problem will do.

First, I was completely missing I was echoing the value from the function radioInputs, which is the function called by the original calling function formInputTypeSelector.  What I wanted was the result of radioInputs being run through the foreach in formInputTypeSelector.  I changed function radioInput to return $inputForm to get that part straightened out.

Second, identifying the above lead me to see I wasn't collecting the loop result each time function radioInputs was being called by the foreach in function formInputTypeSelector. I added the variable $outputForm and concatenated the function radioInputs return value each time through the foreach loop.

Third, I did not have anything being output by the formInputTypeSelector and so added a return of the $outputForm variable after the foreach loop was done running.

And finally, I made my dynamic form variable $category concatenate the call to function formInputTypeSelector and ultimately after all the items had been gather ed into $category, the code echo's $category and my function call now stays in the HTML document flow and all is well.

Here is the final test code working the way I wanted it to.

```
    <?php 
    $category = '';
    $inputForm = '';

    // 4.0  Track
    $doorFinishTrack = array(
        '140' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 0, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '220' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '240' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '440' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '540' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '640' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 0, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '740' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 0, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 1, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 1
        ),
        '2100' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 1, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 0
        ),
        '3300' => array('Aluminum' => 1, 'Dark Bronze' => 0, 'Clear' => 1, 'Gold' => 0, 'Curvable' => 0, 'Recessed Track Channel' => 0, 'Heavy Duty Aluminum Ceiling Guard with Seperate Track' => 1
        )
    );

    //parse the call and pass on the specific input type function
    function formInputTypeSelector ($inputArray, $series, $finish, $inputType, $arg1, $arg2) {
            // Call input type function
        $outputForm = '';
            foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
                $inputName = $finish . $key;
                $inputLabel = $key;
                $inputFunction = $inputType . 'Inputs';
                $outputForm .= $inputFunction($inputName, $inputLabel, $arg1, $arg2);
                // echo $outputForm;
            }
            return $outputForm;
    } //end formInputTypeSelector

    // Specific input types called by formInputTypeSelector
    function radioInputs ($inputName, $inputLabel) {
        $inputForm = '';
        $inputForm .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $inputName . '" id="' . $inputName . '">' . $inputLabel . '</br>';
        return $inputForm;
    } //end radioInputs

    // other types of input functions
        // ... code here

    //dynamically build the form based on the array called and the input form type desired.
        $finish = 'Track';
        $series = 140;
        $category .= 'Where the form starts</div> <!-- End tracksGroup -->';
        $category .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        $category .= '<div><!-- inputs -->';
        $category .= formInputTypeSelector((${'doorFinish' . $finish}[$series]), $series, $finish, 'radio', '', '');
        $category .= '</div><!-- end inputs -->';
        $category .= 'Where the form ends<div class="clearfix"></div>';

        echo $category;
     ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should make radioInputs() return what you are echoing and echo it where you would like to.

```
    function radioInputs ($inputName, $inputLabel) {
    $inputForm = '';
    $inputForm .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $inputName . '" id="' . $inputName . '">' . $inputLabel . '</br>';
    return $inputForm;
} //end radioInputs
```

Comment: The problem is it needs to be in the dynamic form.  There are other items being built around the function return.  So return $inputForm either needs to echo right in place and inline within $category (the variable being used to build the dynamic form) or needs to be concatenated as part of $category.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your post.  Reviewing what you said is what made me see the the first error that then let me see the rest and cascaded into my figuring it out.  Much appreciation!